# What Is the Difference Between These Two Definitions? Infinite Orthonormal Systems and Completeness

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, definition, inner-products, orthonormal

The following are two definitions from Appendix C (Linear Spaces Review) of *Introduction to Laplace Transforms and Fourier Series, Second Edition*, by Phil Dyke:

[image]
[image]

I'm wondering what the difference is between these two definitions?

And shouldn't they both be $= 0$, since the inner product results in a scalar?

Comment: I think that are the same thing. The interesting fact is that a system is complete if and only is a topological base for the space

Comment: The definitions are identical. But what do you mean by "shouldn't they both be =0"?

Comment: @PaulFrost Thanks for the clarification. One is $= \mathbf{0}$ and the other is $= 0$. Since we're dealing with inner products, the result should always be the scalar $0$, right?

Comment: Okay, I see. The boldface **0** is a typo.

Comment: @PaulFrost Ok, thanks for the clarification. I'm guessing this was an error, since the definitions are identical and relatively close together in the text.